# Can an “s”-form plural follow an “s”-form possessive?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

This is best described via an example. I believe this might be technically correct, but sounds clumsy:

> You need to look through all the chemicals shelves

There are multiple shelves, of type chemical. There is a *chemicals shelf* times many/plural. On the other hand you could have:

> You need to look through all the chemical shelves

This sounds better, but to me implies that the shelves themselves are chemicals. Obviously context factors in, in that most people would know that the shelves are not chemicals.

Comment: Don't we have Electronics Engineers and such? Your doubts are certainly unfounded.

Comment: @Kris: I'm not sure if my doubts are unfounded, when there seems to be a mix of answers, some indicating with the 's', some without.

Comment: @Kris, I guess that's because an *electronic* engineer would have different connotations :)

Comment: @MattЭллен - This is my exact point. Maybe my example wasn't clear, but there is a distinct difference between electronic engineer, and electronics engineer. One is a robot, one is not. Although not as clear, there is a slight difference between a chemical shelf and a chemicals shelf

Comment: @MattЭллен: Pl also see my comment about material of construction etc., under Barrie's answer.

Comment: @Kris: Not to try to justify asking a question in the first place, but the amount of conversation this is generating shows, in my opionion, that there is merit in asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plural modifiers are entirely acceptable.

Your doubt about the validity of the plural form comes from a rule in the past that noun modifiers had to be singular (apple tree, vegetable soup, rubber chicken) but today this is not an absolute and there are many examples of plural noun modifiers in everyday use, for example, parts departments, schools superintendents and options markets.

In Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, the following situations are listed where a plural modifier may be used:

> 1. the singular form might lead to ambiguity
>      an Arts degree (a degree in the
>      humanities) as opposed to an art
>      degree (a degree in fine art)
> 2. there is no singular form of a noun (in pluralia tantum)
>      a customs officer
> 3. there is a need to denote variety
>      a soft drinks manufacturer [but] a
>      car manufacturer
> 4. a topical issue comes forth, often in newspaper stories. Quirk cites
>      examples of Watergate reporting from
>      newspapers:
>      the tapes issue
>      the tapes compromise
>      the Watergate tapes affair
>      the White House tapes mystery and other examples, including jobs cut.

In your case, *chemicals shelf* might be used because of the variety of chemicals.  However, I disagree about the potential for confusion. Taking the example of the *electronic engineer*, when could that ever be interpreted as some sort of robotic device?  No such thing even exists.  The same applies to *mechanical engineer* but in that case there's no alternative.

Comment: An electronic engineer doesn't exist yet because the electronics engineers haven't succeeded in building it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use -s' that means possessive and plural.

> You need to look through all the chemicals' shelves

Comment: In such constructions the noun has an attributive function, so no apostrophe is needed.

Comment: -1 pl. see Barrie's answer below.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: To my ear, "the chemical shelves" would be correct if it were referring all shelves that are used for storing chemicals in general, but "the chemical's shelves" or "the chemicals' shelves" would be correct if it were referring to the shelves that are used for storing one or more specific chemicals, e.g. if the sentence was in response to "I can't find the chemical(s) needed for Experiment Six".  Would you agree with such usage?

Comment: @supercat:The most likely response would be 'Have you looked on the shelf where we usually keep them?'

Comment: @BarrieEngland: To that particular question, that could work, but I don't know that it detracts from my point: "I can't find the special tubes needed to mix the chemical(s) for Experiment Six".  I would think a construct like "chemical's shelves" or "chemicals' shelves" would be a reasonable and natural response if e.g. there were groups of shelves which held chemicals for the various experiments, and most glassware was stored on glassware shelves, but the group of shelves for this particular experiment held the (perhaps non-glass) test tubes it required.  My main point was that...

Comment: ...I would regard the phrases "the chemical's shelves" and "the chemicals' shelves" as having meanings which are different from "the chemical shelves". While relatively few situations would require the former phrases' meanings, the phrases should be used on the occasions when their meaning coincides with what the speaker is trying to say. To use a rough analogy, even if 90% of the time the word "axel" is written, the writer misspelled "axle", on the occasions when one is discussing a skating jump, one should not be afraid to spell the jump as "axel" (the only correct spelling).

Answer (score 0):

*Book shelves*, not *books shelves*, *DVD shelves*, not *DVDs shelves*, so, yeh, *chemical shelves*, not *chemicals shelves*. Unless you really want to.

Comment: Except, of course, chemical(s) shelves, where I tend to agree with the OP. see also my comment about EEs above.

Comment: @Kris 'Medicine shelves' or 'medicines shelves'? I reckon it can go either way.

Comment: Agreed, either way, depending on something there. An electronic engineer would be a sort of a robot, while an electronics engineer would be a human who knows electronics engineering. :)

Comment: @Kris How about the place where you keep cleaning stuff? Isn't that a 'broom cupboard', rather than a 'brooms cupboard'?

Comment: Yes. It is possible to use the preceding word as a material of construction and such in some cases, and not so in others.

Comment: @Kris: Actually, I can see that in the singular, at least, 'chemicals shelf' is more likely than 'chemical shelf'.

Comment: All shelves are made of chemicals, always, but it's extremely unlikely that you'd come across a series of shelves made up of pure hyrdrogen, or pure carbon, or pure xenon, or pure copper sulfate, etc. Thus "chemical shelves" will pretty much never be misinterpreted. And I'd say it should be "chemical shelf" even if you store more than one chemical there. Shelves are not restricted to storing only one thing.