# "Sonata of..." or "The sonata of..."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For example, what's more grammatically correct (or at least common practice) "Sonata of Awakening" or "The Sonata of Awakening"?

Comment: Look at the names here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonata#Famous_sonatas  To stick with traditional naming practices you ought to name it along the lines of: Sonata in <your key> for <your instrument>  OR <your instrument> Sonata No. 1  OR Awakening (Sonata in <your key>)  But I think this is off-topic on ELU.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for opinions on naming of musical compositions.

Comment: @Jim Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Sonata of Awakening*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOVkUY39GWI) (yay, Zelda!) sounds a lot better to me personally without 'the' in front of it.

Because **sonata** means *a solo composition*, it sounds more natural at the end.

What I mean is:

- *Solo composition* of Awakening

Sounds less natural than:

- Awakening *solo composition* (Awakening Sonata).

However, that might be a personal bias as I am more familiar with musical titles where the word *sonata* comes at the end.

Here are a few of note:

- [Piano Sonata No 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_%28Beethoven%29)/"Moonlight Sonata" (Beethoven)
- [All sonatas by Mozart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sonatas_by_Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart)
- [Devil's Trill Sonata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Trill_Sonata) (Tartini)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ha, seems like I'm not the only Zelda fan in the site.

Comment: Somehow, 'Awakening Sonata' hasn't got quite the ring to it that 'Moonlight Sonata' has. Nor 'Psalms Symphony' that of 'Symphony of Psalms' [Stravinsky]. Nor, for that matter, 'Goddesses Symphony' that of 'Symphony of the Goddesses'. And as for 'Bells Carol' ...

Comment: @dwin Ashworth How about "Sonata of Solitude" or "Solitude Sonata"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Whatever floats your boat!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, because I nitpick, *Goddesses Symphony* is wrong. It would be *Goddesses' Symphony* because it is posesive in this case (which is why it's *Symphony of the Goddesses*). Just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: It appears about as 'possessive' a construction as 'Carnival of the Animals' to me ['The concert was **named after** the Golden Goddesses in The Legend of Zelda series', Wikipedia], and as ["the removal of the apostrophe from 'plural nouns in phrases which express affiliation {rather than being true possessives}. . . is widespread in the English-speaking world' "](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78476/whats-the-correct-plural-possessive-of-kids) your use of 'wrong' is wrong.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's actually interesting, and thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to  a piece of music that you have composed, you can call it as you prefer!