# Proper pronunciation of plural possessives

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, possessives

I'm compiling a word list with accurate pronunciations and am hitting a brick wall. What are the proper American pronunciations of the following plural possessives, and by extension, similar words?

boys'
caterpillars'
classes'
companies'

I have done extensive research on the online dictionaries (Cambridge, Oxford, Merriam Webster) and none provide the *pronunciations* for the plurals of the words I am including in our educational software. The four hardcover dictionaries I possess, also do not provide the pronunciations for the plurals.

This is not a good fit for ELL, because I am not *learning* the English language (See my bio). I am trying to determine the non-colloquial pronunciation for a group of words that are not well documented in dictionaries. According to the FAQ this is fit for this site, not ELL.

Comment: Hello, Annie. This would be a good fit on our sister site, ELL.

Comment: Sorry English SE, but one has to wonder - as none of the dictionaries LIST the pronunciations for plurals, and this is rather hard to find (if anyone tries), there isn't much "research" to do, and this is a perfectly good question. Besides that, your own FAQ says that pronunciation questions are legitimate. Third, if (http://english.stackexchange.com/q/78476/138131) is elementary yet okay, why isn't this? More explanation is needed as to "why"...I know Annie, and I think you just lost a member with a LOT of English experience b/c of this...she is NOT an ELL.

Comment: The arrogant and close-minded attitude that I have been greeted with by certain members regarding this question is enough to drive off any professional.  A more caring, insightful attitude would improve community relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural possessive has the same pronunciation as the plural.

- *boys’* /bɔɪz/
- *caterpillars’* /ˈkæɾɚˌpɪlɚz/
- *classes’* /ˈklæsəz/
- *companies’* /ˈkʌmpəniz/

Like the plural, if a word ends in an /s/ or /z/ sound, the possessive suffix is read /ɪz/, e.g., *princesses* and *princess’(s)*.